# React Hook Form Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-query

I am trying to watch a field called party. after selecting those fields list of products will need to be rendered. I'm using react hook form where I used watch hook to subscribe to change.

```
<FormProvider {...methods}>
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
   <Select
       ref={ref}
       options={partyOptions}
       value={partyOptions.find(
              (c) => c.value === value
       )}
       onChange={(val: any) => onChange(val.value)}
       name={name}
        />
       )}
      <div className="card-body row">
        <ProductContext.Provider value={[product, setProduct]}>
            <ProductList partyId={partyId} />
        </ProductContext.Provider>
      </div>
</form>
```

On productlist component, i passed partyId as props and try to access API according to the partyId

```
export function ProductList({ partyId }: { partyId: any }) {
const { control } = useFormContext(); // retrieve all hook methods

const [productOptions, setProductOptions] = useState([] as any);
const productQuery = useQuery("products", () => searchProduct(partyId), {
    enabled: partyId !== undefined,
});

if (productQuery.isFetched) {
  setProductOptions(
    productQuery.data.data.map((d: any) => ({
     value: d.id,
     label: d.name,
   }))
  );
}
```

I am getting `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` Is there any solution to not render multiple times?

Comment: It looks like once `productQuery.isFetched` becomes true, you will call `setProductOptions` infinitely. You need to add more logic to make sure you only set state when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to add more logic, `setProductOptions` is called at each react render. For example, you can use a `useEffect` to call `setProductOptions` only once.

```
export function ProductList({ partyId }: { partyId: any }) {
   const { control } = useFormContext(); // retrieve all hook methods

  const [productOptions, setProductOptions] = useState([] as any);
  const productQuery = useQuery("products", () => searchProduct(partyId), {
      enabled: partyId !== undefined,
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    if (productQuery.isFetched) {
      setProductOptions(
        productQuery.data.data.map((d: any) => ({
            value: d.id,
            label: d.name,
          })
        )
     );
   }
  }, [productQuery.isFetched, setProductOptions]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
  if (productQuery.isFetched) {
    setProductOptions(
      productQuery.data.data.map((d: any) => ({
        value: d.id,
        label: d.name,
      })
    )
  );
```

Every time the component is rendered, it triggers another state update with `setProductOptions`, which then causes another render and the cycle repeats infinitely. Consider using a `useEffect` hook instead:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (productQuery.isFetched) {
      setProductOptions(
        productQuery.data.data.map((d: any) => ({
          value: d.id,
          label: d.name,
        })
      )
    }
  }, [productQuery.isFetched);
```

Some more info on `useEffect` is available here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Why would you useEffect though? This is clearly derived state which shouldn’t be stored, but derived…